# all multiples of 3 from 1 to 100 by a for loop in c++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

```
for (int x = 3; x <= 100; x%3 == 0; x++ ) {
 printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

I'm using the book "how to program C" by Deitel and there is this exercise, for this for loop, and they want me to fix it and get the output of all multiples of 3.

I've solved this with an if statement. But im curious if there is another way to fix it within the loop.

what i did was this :

```
for (int x = 3; x <= 100;  x++ ) {

 if(x%3 == 0){
      printf("%d\n", x);
   }

}
```

Comment: `for (int x = 3; x <= 100;  x += 3 )`

Comment: No loop needed. Even with a non-constant upper border, this can be calculated in one statement. Think of the story of the pupil being assigned to add up all numbers from 1 to 100.

Comment: You can't learn C++ from a C book.

Comment: Is your intention to add the numbers or print them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add 3 instead of 1 after each iteration, so that it will guarantee to be a mutiple of 3

Something like this:

```c
for (int x = 3; x <= 100; x += 3) 
{
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```